# How to receive UDP broadcast packets on a PARTICULAR interface?

Tags: ios, sockets, udp, broadcast

On an iPhone I have created a UDP socket and bound it to the WLAN interface. I enabled `SO_BROADCAST` and I am able to send broadcast packets to the network (confirmed by a client running on my notebook.) But the UDP socket on the iPhone is unable to receive broadcast packets.

In my opinion this is a kernel bug, because not allowing a socket with `SO_BROADCAST` enabled to receive any broadcast packet, is a bad design decision.

The problem is further described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496761/udp-broadcast-being-sent-but-not-received) and [here](http://developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?pid=32260). The most popular solution to this problem is to bind to `INADDR_ANY`. However, it would be nice to be able to bind an UDP socket to only one interface while still receiving broadcast packets! Is there really no way to achieve this?

(When I bind a socket to 192.168.1.7 on a class C net (/24), it should accept packets sent to 192.168.1.7 and packets sent to 192.168.1.255!)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

pls check below link may be it's helpful.

[Receive udp broadcast packets ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674450/receive-udp-broadcast-packets-ios)

[iPhone UDP broadcast and response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630784/iphone-udp-broadcast-and-response)

[iOS UDP broadcast vs. PHP UDP broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901612/ios-udp-broadcast-vs-php-udp-broadcast)

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

Comment: Dude, you just answered the much easier question "How to receive UDP broadcast packets on INADDR_ANY interface?" I know how to do that already. Btw, I already use CocoaAsyncSocket.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571038/how-to-identify-senders-ip-address-of-a-udp-packet-received-on-ios-device

Comment: you still don't understand. in the link you provided, the socket is bound to INADDR_ANY!

Comment: @Michael have you found any workaround for this one?

Comment: @ValeriiHiora: unfortunately not. i had another idea lately, but I haven't tested it yet, because I don't need to solve this problem any longer: maybe you can bind the socket to the local broadcast address? So, create 2 sockets: one bound to "192.168.0.4" and the other bound to "192.168.0.255" and receive messages on both. (to get the broadcast addr you need `getifaddrs` and then `bc_addr=ip_addr | ( ~netmask)` ). use at your own risk...